# Writing file with CURL through NDK throws Fatal Signal 11

Tags: android, c++, curl, android-ndk

The following snippet is what I compile with Android NDK. From Java I pass a folder to write a file. I've tried to execute `mkdir` from Java and from C++ (one at time though) and I got the same result. In the following snippet I'm creating the folder in C++.

```
int statusMKDIR = mkdir(folderToWrite, 0755);
LOGD(string("status mkdir: " + to_string(statusMKDIR)).c_str()); // this is always -1
CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode res;
string outfilename = string(folderToWrite+string("/file.zip"));
curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(outfilename.c_str(),"wb");

    // header
    struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "append");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
    // end header

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    if (fp)
        LOGD("fp exists");
    else {
        LOGD("we're gonna craaaaaaaaaash"); // here is what it prints when it throws the Fatal Signal 11
    }

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    std::ostringstream out;
    out << res;
    string content = out.str();

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

So, this happens only **SOMETIMES**. What I thought is that the folder wasn't released. I thought this could be useful:

```
    if (fp)
        LOGD("fp exists");
    else {
        while (!fp) {
            fp = fopen(outfilename.c_str(),"wb");
        }
    }
```

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    LOGD("writting");
    size_t written = 0;
    if (size > 0 && nmemb > 0) {
        written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    }
    LOGD("ended writting"); // when it sometimes crashes, it doesn't reach this point.
    return written;
}

but this ends in a infinite loop.

How could I debug it ? because sometimes I can write, and some others I can't. I can't reproduce why sometimes it doesn't work.

My stacktrace is:

> A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x30 in tid 29956 (AsyncTask #2)

Thank you very much.

Comment: where is your `size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)`? Also, crash usually produces much more info, which can be analyzed with **ndk-stack**. Have you tried that?

Comment: I'm adding it. I'll try to analyze in two minutes with ndk :). Thanks!